# Android -- treatment for ListView rows based on behavior?

Tags: android, mobile, android-listview, cross-platform

In iOS, we can give our UITableViewCell objects different appearances for different behavior.  So for drill-down, we typically use UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator, for info, we use UITableViewCellAccessoryInfoButton, and so on.

Does Android have anything similar?  That is, a graphical treatment that will make sense to users, depending on the behavior of the row.

Answer (score 0):

In Android there is no such preconfigured cell accessory indicators. Instead of that, Android developer inflates different kind of layout in the `ListAdapter`. By using standard layouts like `android.R.simple_list_item_1`, `android.R.simple_list_item_checked`, `android.R.simple_list_item_single_choice` etc. you can implement difference appearance of list items. The names of the layout are self explanatory. In case of doubts, it's always possible to see source code of those layouts in Android sources. If none of standard layouts is sufficient, it is common to create an own layout for a row and use it.

Here is an example of very simple list activity, which might help to make the answer more understandable.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

// We extend an activity that gives us a list
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private String[] items = { "first", "second ", "third" }; 

    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         // Here we use already existing adapter with layout.simple_list_item_1
         // We are free to use other layouts here too
         ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

         // here we assign this adapter to the list
         setListAdapter(adapter);
     }

}
```

It is also important to mention, there is no disclose indicator in Android Design. Developers are free so add such by themselves, but classical Android Design prescribes to not use one.